# Force wordpress page to refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

**==SITUATION==**

Currently, I am using Wordpress to display announcement.

There is 1 server to host Wordpress and 4 other PC to show the announcement. Each PC have their own page URL to show the announcement. For example

1. PC1 (1st floor) - http://localhost/announcement1
2. PC2 (2nd floor) - http://localhost/announcement2
3. PC3 (3rd floor) - http://localhost/announcement3
4. PC4 (4th floor) - http://localhost/announcement4
5. Admin PC

Currently, let say if I do some announcement changes to **http://localhost/announcement1**, then I need to walk to 1st floor and manually refresh the page to get the latest announcement. This goes same with others announcement.

**==QUESTION==**

1. What I want to accomplish is, I would like to force the PC1 browser to refresh the page directly from the Wordpress admin dashboard (PC1 automatically refresh when the page is saved/updated). Is it possible?

I searched all over the web for the solution but I don't know the exact keyword to search for and have no luck.

Thank you

Comment: you could make it refresh every hour or something like that

Comment: Have you tried anything for this? If so - please share, otherwise, please ask a question that has an *actual* issue, i.e. the problem you have, what you have tried (minimal, complete and verifiable example), what the expected behaviour is and what the current behaviour is plus any error messages that we need to help, not asking us to do it for you as that is not what we are here for

Comment: or, write a script, that checks if your content, is equal of the content on the URL, run that every 5 minutes - if it does not have equal content, make js refresh the page

Comment: why don't you try to set timeinterval to refresh the page every 10 or 15 min ?

Comment: @SamSwift웃I'm not asking someone do the code for me. What I looking for is some sort of reference or idea suggestion for the concept how it can be done.

Comment: I guess I will go for time interval.

Answer (score 3):

The most simple way would be to set a refresh meta for your announcement page. For example, 5 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5">
```

I don't know if you have a theme that you can modify, but one route to go about this is by using the hook on the wp_head action. Like this:

```
function wp_50642305_add_refresh_header() {
   echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5">';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_refresh_header' );
```

You could place that in functions.php of your theme or perhaps in a plugin file.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head

Comment: For all we appreciate you trying to help, the question asked is too broad to receive the best answer for this as the OP does not provide us any code to fix, rather asking us to write it for them, which we are not here for

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Besides the time interval, when visitor visit our page, technically is it possible that we can force our visitor page/browser to refresh directly from our Wordpress admin dashboard with a click of a button? if is it possible, how it can be done? using javascript/php/html? Could someone point me to any reference?

Comment: You might want to checkout Ajax. You could make a script that checks on updates and only update the specific sections of your website that need to be refreshed. That would be a more friendly solution to your visitor perhaps.

Comment: @JeffreyVanRossum thanks for the suggestion. I will check out Ajax

Answer (score 3):

After a while, I found a plugin that helps what I want to achieve.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-refresh/

With a single click, I manage to "force" refresh the client browser.

**"The way the plugin works is that the user’s browser will check with the website every two minutes to make sure it’s up to date, and if not it’ll refresh."**

Hope this will help others who are looking for the same solution.